# SQL query to get row wise total

Tags: sql-server

I'm working with SQL Server 2008. I want to get the row wise total for the table and want to merge the 2 string column names for the total column. I have below table data

```
Region Test  taken  Nottaken 
India  AA    1      0 
UK     AS    3      4 
US     AF    1      1
```

I want the result set like below

```
Region Test  taken  Nottaken Total 
India  AA    1      0        1 
UK     AS    3      4        7 
US     AF    1      1        2 
total        5      5        10
```

How to write query?

Comment: please post the query u tried to manage this

Comment: Here is a guide on posting T-SQL related questions: http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: There are already duplicate questions on this site for how to add a total column, and how to add a total row.   This question does not show any research effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with a UNION to add your total row like this:

```
SELECT * FROM(
    SELECT region,test,taken,nottaken,taken+nottaken as total
    FROM YourTable
    UNION 
    SELECT 'region','test',sum(taken),sum(nottaken) ,sum(nottaken+taken)
    FROM YourTable)
ORDER BY CASE WHEN region <> 'region' then 0 else 1 end
```

Comment: @downvoter care to explain?

Comment: Don't know why somebody has downvoted this answer. Maybe because you give an answer for "bad" question? Anyway, here is my up.

Answer (score 0):

Just do the math in the select statement adding the two columns together...

```
Select Region, Test, Taken, NotTaken, Taken+notTaken as total
from table
```